# How do I ignore JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS when running my TESTNG suite?

Tags: java, selenium, testng

When I try to run my testng.xml file, it throws the following error:

> org.testng.TestNGException: java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:341)     at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:88)  at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)  at
>   org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.testng.xml.Parser.parse(Parser.java:184)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:311)     ... 3
>   more
>   Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -agentlib:jvmhook Picked up
>   _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xrunjvmhook -Xbootclasspath/a:"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified Functional
>   Testing\bin\java_shared\classes";"C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Unified
>   Functional Testing\bin\java_shared\classes\jasmine.jar"

I have UFT and Selenium on this same machine but I don't want Selenium to pick up environment variables related to UFT.  Is there a way to ignore those when running the test?

If I remove them from my ENV, UFT will not run.  Surely there is a way to run a simple Selenium test while ignoring those variables without having to use a different machine, right?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may redefine them with blank/space value. If you use eclipse, you may go to Run Configuration and in the Environment tab, to do the same.

This is a very annoying problem and HP should have handled it in their on configuration rather then polluting whole system environment.